# Firefox debugger doesn't show js files

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I have a .NET MVC 4 program which include a file with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Example/Example.js"></script>
```

at the end of a page.
I inserted a `debugger;` there.
When I use Chrome, it opens it in a new VM[randomId] tab.
When I use firefox, it opens my HTML page where, if I press F10 it go throw.
The call stack is ok, but I can't view the correct source .js file!
How can I fix this?

I'm using Firefox Developer Edition 58.0b5 (64-bit)